# Finding Access Token using Okta in Spring Boot Test

Tags: spring-boot, okta, spring-boot-test, okta-signin-widget

Trying to get the accesstoken for okta authentication.
Have used the OktaSiginWidget in the frontEnd(ReactJs).
For backEnd(Spring Boot) want to test all the apis using this access token generated by okta.

Following is the test method written

```
        @Test
        public void testOktaAuthorization() {
            String tokenEndpoint = "https://dev-10835870.okta.com/api/v1/authn";
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            Map<String, Object> requestBody = new HashMap<>();
            requestBody.put("client_id", clientId);
            requestBody.put("username",email);
            requestBody.put("password",password);

            HttpEntity<Map<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, headers);


            ResponseEntity<Map> responseEntity = new RestTemplate().postForEntity(tokenEndpoint, requestEntity, Map.class);

            sessionToken = (String) responseEntity.getBody().get("sessionToken");

            final String authorizeEndpoint = domain + "/oauth2/default/v1/authorize";
            final UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(authorizeEndpoint)
                    .queryParam("response_type", "token")
                    .queryParam("scope", "openid")
                    .queryParam("state", "TEST")
                    .queryParam("nonce", "TEST")
                    .queryParam("client_id", clientId)
                    .queryParam("redirect_uri", redirectUri)
                    .queryParam("sessionToken", sessionToken);

            final HttpHeaders headers1 = new HttpHeaders();
            headers1.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

            final HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>("", headers1);

            final ResponseEntity<String> response = new RestTemplate().exchange(builder.build().toUri(),HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
            System.out.println(response);

        }
```

Problem -> Getting 400 Bad Request.

Please review the code.

Comment: There are couple questions: 1) why do you need to get a separate token in your backend if you already have one in the frontend? why not to pass it to the backend? 2) usually /authorize requires a browser redirect, not a direct backend call (though there are ways) 3) 400 which you are getting will be accompanied by an HTML page with an error message (if you care to get the content)

Comment: Basically i am testing my endpoints which require the access token coming from okta. One approach can be to use the token  manually and save it in configuration file for testing purpose but wanted to automate this process in the backend.

Comment: For that I suggest to use an application configured with client_credentials flow. This way you don't need to jump through a hoop to obtain a token and just do one single call to /token endpoint